# Proving an upper bound to F(x)+G(x)

Tags: java, big-o, proof, upperbound

I have stumbled upon the following question:
If `f(x),g(x) > 1` for every `x`, prove/disprove the following:

`f(x)+g(x)= O(f(x)*g(x))`

I dont know how to start the proof, this is very basic for my level, please help.

Answer (score 0):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.

You basically need to show that there is a positive constant `M` and a number `x0` such that:

```
abs(f(x)+g(x)) <= M*abs(f(x)*g(x))
```

for all `x >= x0`.

Which is trivial. I will omit this part, please do it yourself.

Comment: Should I divide the problem into cases?

Comment: @EiadAmer No. You should prove exactly what my comment says you should prove. Hint: divide both paths by `f(x)*g(x)`. What will you get?

Comment: You get `abs(1/g(x) + 1/f(x)) <= M`. As `f(x) > 1`, `g(x) > 1` for every `x` the `1/f(x) < 1`, `1/g(x) < 1`. Meaning `abs(1/g(x) + 1/f(x)) < 2`, so you can choose any `M => 2`.